# Can Xorg be configured to only use part of the physical screen?

Tags: linux, display, xorg

My laptop, a Dell Latitude E5440, has a crack down the left edge of the screen. The rest of the screen is fully usable. While the replacement arrives, I am interested in knowing if there's some way to configure X to use only the rightmost part of the screen, as though my framebuffer were somewhat narrower, and offset so that the broken part of the LCD will not get used.

I dual-boot Debian and Gentoo, but as this would be a matter of configuration, I suppose that doesn't matter.

Comment: [xrandr](https://www.x.org/wiki/Projects/XRandR/) may do what you want.